# File upload and overwrite file with same name in php

Tags: php, html

I making an application that allows users to upload a file in a directory. the if user want to change file(uploaded file is wrong document) user can overwrite it with new file.
For example user uploaded id card with with wrong file, then user can change the file with correct file by clicking a button.

Code:

HTML

```
<form  method="post">
                    <input class="form-control white_bg" id="allfile" name="allFile"  type="file" required><br>
                        <button type="submit" name="save" class="btn btn-info btn-min-width mr-1 mb-1"">Save</button>
                    </form>
```

PHP

```
   $file = $_FILES["allfile"]["tmp_name"];
    $name = $fileName;
    $extensionPhoto = substr($photo,strlen($photo)-4,strlen($photo));
    $allowed_extensions = array(".jpg","jpeg",".png",".gif",".pdf",".PDF");
    $file1 = $fileName;
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$file],"userdocs/".$file1);
```

Comment: You can try use `rename` php function. Check please the documentation - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php

Answer (score 0):

Check if the file already exists. Delete it and move the new file

```
   if(file_exists("userdocs/".$file1)) {
        unlink("userdocs/".$file1);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$file],"userdocs/".$file1);
    }
```